# How to allow traffic for SSH 22 using iptables for one specific ip address and internal networks

Tags: iptables

Allowing one specific address(1.2.3.4):

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s 1.2.3.4 --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
```

Allowing internal networks IPs between 192.168.0.0-192.168.255.255:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s 192.168.0.0/16 --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
```

Allowing connection from localhost:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s 127.0.0.0/8 --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
```

Now my questions are how to allow connection for 10 A and 172 A classes IPs?

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s 10.0.0.0/8 --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
```

and

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s 172.0.0.0/8 --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
```

or

It **must** contain the /24 ? I'm not really sure which one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those are correct:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s 10.0.0.0/8 --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s 172.16.0.0/12 --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
```

Explanation is here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network